# cgi script execution ans display of result on same page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to execute a cgi shell script passing some parameter maybe through a form and show the result of script on the same page via pop up window or anything
my html form code is

```
<form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/cgi_try.sh" >
<input type="text" name="ip" />
<input type="submit" value="PING"/>
```

my shell script goes like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<title>PING</title>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
ip=`echo $QUERY_STRING | cut -d '=' -f2`
if ping -c1 $ip > /dev/null
then
    echo "ALIVE"
else
    echo "DEAD"
fi
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
exit 0
```

what i need, is to show the result of ping on the same page as the form

Comment: Welcome to SO !! Read [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) & come back again with relevant question.

Comment: @Rikesh cud u please help me now

Comment: Use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function to get output of shell command in php.